# Kotlin/Android - Button pressed should continue scroll

Tags: android, kotlin, scroll, ontouchlistener

I have a button that I want to scroll with a `webview` inside (but it could be something else) when pressed. 
Unfortunately I can't find a solution for it in Kotlin. 
This is the code I have now:

```
val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonx)
   var count:Int = 0
   button.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
      when (event?.action) {
         MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> report_web_page.scrollBy(0, count++)
      }
      v?.onTouchEvent(event) ?: true
 }
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a ClickListener:

```
val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonx)
   button.setOnClickListener { report_web_page.pageDown(true)}
```

> public boolean pageDown (boolean bottom)
>
> Scrolls the contents of this WebView down by half the page size.